# If $|h_n'(0)|$ tends to 1 as n tends to $\infty$,does $h_n(0)$ tends to zero?Here $h_n$ is a sequence of analytic maps from D to D.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $h_n$ be a sequence of analytic maps from D to D.If $|h_n'(0)|$ tends to 1
as n tends to $\infty$,does $h_n(0)$ tends to zero?

I guess there should be some theorem about this but I can not think of one. And how to explain this in intuition?

Comment: What if $h_n = \operatorname{id}_D + c$ for come $c ∈ ℂ$? Er, $h_n \colon D → D$. Nevermind. On the other hand, what do you mean by $D$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes: this follows quickly from the [Schwarz-Pick theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz.E2.80.93Pick_theorem), which is a quantitative version of the Schwarz lemma. (assuming your $D$ is the unit disk)

My intuition here was: if the limit function $h(z) = \lim_{n\to\infty} h_n(z)$ existed and was analytic, then it would satisfy $|h'(0)|=1$, which is a case of equality in the Schwarz lemma that forces $h(z) = e^{i\theta}z$ for some real $\theta$. There's no reason that $h(z)$ has to exist; but maybe, I thought, there's a quantitative version of the Schwarz lemma that says that if $f(0)\ne0$ then $|f'(0)|$ must be bounded away from $1$, with the bound depending on $|f(0)|$. Wikipedia told me the rest!